# Передача данных из формы в mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

Не могу передать данные из html формы в mysql. Подключение - работает. Выбор таблицы работает исправно. Форма данные отправляет на след.страницу, но не может в бд.

Код index.php:

```
<form method="post" action="up.php">
    <div class="col-sm-10">
         <div class="form-group label-floating">
           <label class="control-label">Ник</label>
             <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nick" required>
         </div>

         <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Примечания" rows="1" name="not"></textarea>

         <input class="datepicker form-control" name="datetime" placeholder="Дата" type="text"/>


         <button id="bsub" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-round" name="submit">Отправить</button>
    </div>

</form>
```

Код up.php:

```
<?php
$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'login', 'password');

if($connection == false)
{
    /* echo '$connection = Нет; '; */
    exit();
} else
{
    /* echo '$connection = Да; ';*/
}

$db=mysqli_select_db($connection, "luck");
mysqli_set_charset("utf8");
if (!$connection || !$db)
{
exit(mysqli_error());
}


$name1 = $_POST['nick'];
$notes1 = $_POST['notes']; 
$date1 = $_POST['datetime'];

 echo ($name1);
 echo ($notes1);
 echo ($date1);


$result = mysqli_query("INSERT INTO `tablica`(`name`, `notes`, `date`) VALUES ('$name1','$notes1','$date')");
if ($result) {
    echo "Данные успешно сохранены!";
}
else {
    echo "Произошла ошибка, пожалуйста повторите попытку.";
} 

?>
```

Comment: Забудьте о вставке данных прямо в sql запрос!!! Используйте подготовленные выражения при работе с базой http://phpfaq.ru/pdo http://php.net/manual/ru/book.pdo.php http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: для проверки на ошибки нужно после `echo "Произошла ошибка, пожалуйста повторите попытку.";` добавить `echo mysqli_error()`;

Comment: по-хорошему вопрос "почему не работает вставка данных в базу данных" и в тексте вопроса все лишнее кроме кода страницы *up.php*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Справочная информация по `mysqli_query()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.query.php)

У Вас не указан идентификатор соединения, полученный с помощью `mysqli_connect()`.

```
$result = mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO `tablica`(`name`, `notes`, `date`) VALUES ('$name1','$notes1','$date')");
```